# cycling images with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, cycle

I have a simple HTML list:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="slideshow1">
            <img class="bradius5 slide1" src="<?php base_url();?> img/ristorante1.jpg" height="150" width="170"/>
            <img class="bradius5 slide1" src="<?php base_url();?> img/ristorante1.jpg" height="150" width="170"/>
            <img class="bradius5 slide1" src="<?php base_url();?> img/ristorante1.jpg" height="150" width="170"/>
            <img class="bradius5 slide1" src="<?php base_url();?> img/ristorante1.jpg" height="150" width="170"/>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="slideshow2">
            <img class="bradius5 slide2" src="<?php base_url();?> img/ristorante1.jpg" height="150" width="170"/>
            <img class="bradius5 slide2" src="<?php base_url();?> img/ristorante1.jpg" height="150" width="170"/>
            <img class="bradius5 slide2" src="<?php base_url();?> img/ristorante1.jpg" height="150" width="170"/>
            <img class="bradius5 slide2" src="<?php base_url();?> img/ristorante1.jpg" height="150" width="170"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to cycle through the images by doing this:

```
$('.slide1,.slide2').hide();

$.each($('.slide1'), function() {
    $(this).fadeIn().delay(1900).fadeOut();
});

$.each($('.slide2'),function() {
    $(this).fadeIn().delay(1900).fadeOut();
});
```

However, it doesn't cycle image by image; it cycles multiple images at a time.

I want to cycle through all the images in the first `li`, then cycle through the images in the second `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because youre delaying all of them at once. The first parameter in the each is the current index.

Try something like this:

```
$.each($('.slide1'),function(i){
     $(this).fadeIn().delay(i*200).fadeOut();
});
```

this will delay each one 200ms from the last

### Update

You should really use a plugin like @ShankarSangoli has suggested and just get it to work with the layout but something like this should work for you as well. (this hasn't been tested but just to get you started)

```
var _slide1 = $('.slide1');
var _slide2 = $('.slide2');
var_count1 = 0;
var _count2 = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    _slide1[_count1].fadeOut(300);
    _slide2[_count2].fadeOut(300);

    _count1 = _count1 >= _slide1.length ? 0 : _count1+=1;
    _count2 = _count2 >= _slide2.length ? 0 : _count2+=1;

    _slide1[_count1].fadeIn(300);
    _slide2[_count2].fadeIn(300);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: yes now somenthings moving on :)   what i would like is to fadeOut and FadeIn .next() image how can i do? :P

Comment: sorry i mean fadeOut current and fadeIn next image :P

Comment: sorry Im confused. which one do you want to fade out and then fade in?

Comment: i would like to fadeOut 1 image then fadeOut the same and fadeIn the next one, this all cycling... so after latest img was shown restart from first image in the <li> block list :))

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use jquery cycle plugin? It offers a lot of features and very easy to use

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/